# How do I match a certain string that does not contain a certain word?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a pretty specific set of requirements defining which strings I want to match, and I have the following working regex:

```
/^#\s*([-a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|$)/
```

This matches: '# keyword' ... As well as: '# Static keyword'

For my final condition, I want to ignore a string if it contains the word: "Static".. I've done a lot of digging, and I can't figure this one out.
The following is my best attempt:

```
/^#\s*(?!Static)([-a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|$)/
```

However, it seems as though I'm woefully far from the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look for `Static` in more places than just right after `#` and whitespace:

```
/^#\s*(?!.*Static)([-a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|$)/
```

By the way, you might want to replace `(?=\s|$)` with `\b` (a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that matches after an alphanumeric word). That would also match if punctuation or something other than whitespace delimits the word you're matching.

Comment: @m.buettner: Right. I had `.*` there before, then I thought he might only want to look at the first "word" - but that didn't make much sense either, so I went back to `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/^(?>[^S]++|S++(?!tatic\b))+$/
```

Or this that allows "electroStatic":

```
/^(?>[^S]++|\BS++|\bS(?!tatic\b))+$/
```